# Refreshing Swing application with Eclipse/MyEclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, myeclipse

Say that we are writing a Java Swing application and we use Eclipse or MyEclipse to develop it. In web applications, you make code changes, you save and your ant deployment file takes care of the deployment of the changed files. Then you just refresh or hard refresh the web page and the changes appear there. Can we do the same thing for a Swing applications so that we don't have to close and open the program from the beginning every time we make a change?

Comment: You can seem them in the 'design view' of some GUI layout editor thingies.  But otherwise, no.  I'd suggest you make a 'test' form of your app. that allows you to navigate to deep within the GUI structure (e.g. a frame that pops a dialog that show the 15th step of a wizard) quickly.

Comment: I know it NetBeans, when in debug mode you can reload changes into the running session, how you might do that in Eclipse I don't know. If running, no you can't. The code, generally, isn't dynamically controlled like it is under most web based solutions

Comment: Eclipse supports Hot code replacement in debug mode, as long as you don't modify the class structure (ie, you don't change the class variables nor any method signature). You can modify code inside a method.

Comment: for me on simple tasks, even an auto restart would work. i.e. the window of app is replaced entirely with new one (as i use auto-hotkey on windows 10 to keep window pinned; & would like new window to be pinned as well)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so because you need hot code replacement ! Maybee using another framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply do that because once JVM is started, it loads the class files once and will not reload it untill next loading request. But you can use `ClassLoader` to load modified class files dynamically.

The following two articles may help:

- [IBM article on "hot class swap"](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cn/java/j-lo-hotswapcls/)
- ["Who Said Runtime Class Reloading Is Hard in Java?"](http://java.dzone.com/runtime-java-reloading-javeleon)

The first one is in Chinese, but you can look at the code and the result. I think the second article is more helpful for a GUI application.

Answer (score 0):

In MyEclipse you can start your application in debug mode instead of run mode and changes you make will be pushed to the target VM; if changes you make cannot be replaced you'll see a dialog informing you the replace failed and you will need to restart your application. You don't need to place any breakpoints in the application, just starting in debug mode is sufficient.

As Guillaume states above, changes to the class structure will typically not be hot-synched, but changes within existing methods should be fine.

Obviously, how successfully hot-synched changes affect your running application would depend on your application design.